# How to change form request format to json format

Tags: php, json, forms, yii

I have an application built on Yii 1.1. I'm having problems with the backend API. Here is the case.

I am new to API building and I have been tasked to build the backend API of a project. Now when it comes to Form submission from the frontend, my Tech Lead says I should change the form request format to JSON. Which I don't have any idea of. I tried to use `file_gets_content('php://input') and json_decode` in the codes below, but still not working.

```
        if (isset($_POST['TblTemplate'])) {
        //getting raw input of request
        var_dump($request = file_get_contents('php://input'));

        //decoding the JSON
        var_dump($input = json_decode($request, true));

        //passing input fields to model attributes
        $model->attributes = $input;

        //validating input fields (getErrors)
        if (!$model->validate()) {
            echo json_encode($model->getErrors());
        } else {
            //inserting (creating) template
            if(!$model->save()) {
                echo json_encode(['error' => 'Could not create template']);
            } else {
                echo json_encode(['success' => true]);
                exit();
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

When I submit the form it gives me fields are empty. I'm very new to this API stuffs please help.
Also when I run var dump or request it outputs this

```
string(156) "TblTemplate%5Bname%5D=Standard+Feedback+Request&TblTemplate%5Bemail%5D=gideon.a%40scopicsoftware.com&TblTemplate%5Bcontent%5D=I+am+a+new+template&yt0=Create"
```

But vardump on input returns null.

Comment: It's a weird situation you're describing. If you have a $_POST it means php://input has been read and processed (a POST is contained in php://input a.k.a. the request body). Meaning you can't send POST data and JSON at the same time, except when JSON data is enclosed in a POST var...

Comment: so how can i change these errors cause I'm really novice at this

Comment: Try to read the raw input and convert it from a JSON object to a php object (or array). If that fails, you'll get a NULL value if it failed - though the value that is given can also be NULL, so try not to send values only... [Read this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more info on JSON decoding

Comment: so should I change the $_POST

Answer (score 1):

Trying to give you a head start:

```
//getting raw input of request
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');

$json = json_decode($request);

if ($json !== null) {
    .... code ...
} else {
    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: the request is not equal to null, but the json is

Comment: also when I var dump the request it does not output a json but some set of scraps

Comment: string(156) "TblTemplate%5Bname%5D=Standard+Feedback+Request&TblTemplate%5Bemail%5D=gideon.a%40scopicsoftware.com&TblTemplate%5Bcontent%5D=I+am+a+new+template&yt0=Create"

Comment: If that is so, then the request does not contain JSON data but POST data. In that case therre is no need for converting anything...

Comment: Oh so its not my fault is from the front end, right?

Comment: Could be, but I don't know about the front-end. All I know is that from a regular front-end, you'd send POST data, not JSON... But that's a typical choice, not that it's prohibited to use other means...

Comment: the front end will be using angular

Comment: I don't know Angular that well, but I think it uses POST to send data.. You may want to [look at this article](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) describing the normal request behavior...